# Difference between Ax-b and f(A)x-f(b)?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, soft-question

I have an understanding how the solution of the following convex optimization behaves for a particular data: $min(norm(Ax-b),2)+norm(x,1))$. In this case $A$ is a known matrix and $b$ is a known vector. We want to find $x$. I want to analyse the case when both $A$ and $b$ are changed by a function. This means the new problem is  $min(norm(f(A)x-f(b)),2)+norm(x,1))$.

This question may be vague as I have not specified the function $f$. Can there be a class of function for which the problem would not deviate much? Or is there any such $f$ which is actually used to get a better or useful optimization problem compare to the original one? Specifically, if the function $f$ is non-linear is there any application, or foe some non-linear $f$ the optimization problem become more attractive than the original one.

Comment: If you specify a linear function $f$, it won't really change the problem significantly.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall, yes the issue is my function is non-linear. I added a new sentence, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You use $f$ on both matrices and vectors. How should that extension be interpreted? Or is $f$ an element-wise function?

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall element wise.

Comment: If there is any solution to the original problem, the solution to the transformed problem will be identical, except it would have $f(A)$ instead of $A$, and $f(b)$ instead of $b$. The only way using $f$ would be useful, then, would be if there is a value of $A^*$ and $b^*$ which makes the problem significantly easier, which we can "force" $f$ to map to. The obvious example is $f=0$, but that's linear. I'm very skeptical that there's anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88716/discussion-between-nathan-j-mcdougall-and-creator).